# Controls to dump key/value pairs

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt

Are there alternative (better) ways to factor out the common parts other than my use of abstract base class?  I find myself following this pattern lately and it makes sense when I code it but sometimes leads to code that is particularly susceptible to obfuscation as time goes by (i.e. I come back to it later and have a hard time remembering how it worked). I am curious to know if it looks good and readable or if maybe it's over-optimized or has other issues.

```
public abstract class DumpKeyValuePairs : Control
{
    static string XsltPath = "~/Controls/DumpKeys.xslt";
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(new Xml {
            DocumentContent = new XElement("keys",
                                    from key in this.Keys
                                    select new XElement("key",
                                                new XAttribute("name", key),
                                                this[key])).ToString(),
            TransformSource = DumpKeyValuePairs.XsltPath,
        });
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
    abstract protected IEnumerable<string> Keys { get; }
    abstract protected string this[string index] { get; }
}

public class DumpServerVariables : DumpKeyValuePairs
{
    protected override IEnumerable<string> Keys
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys; }
    }

    protected override string this[string index]
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables[index]; }
    }
}

public class DumpSessionVariables : DumpKeyValuePairs
{
    protected override string this[string index]
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session[index].ToString(); }
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<string> Keys
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session.Cast<string>(); }
    }
}
```

**XSLT:**

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="keys">
    <table border="1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="key">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

This bit is a little too much to digest:

> ```
> this.Controls.Add(new Xml {
>     DocumentContent = new XElement("keys",
>                             from key in this.Keys
>                             select new XElement("key",
>                                         new XAttribute("name", key),
>                                         this[key])).ToString(),
>     TransformSource = DumpKeyValuePairs.XsltPath,
> });
> ```

The trailing comma is annoying, but the LINQ query syntax is a little bit overboard. The instruction is doing too many things.

Wouldn't this be clearer?

```
Controls.Add(xml);
```

There's no need to qualify `XsltPath` with the `DumpKeyValuePairs` type, even if the field is `static` - you're in the same type anyway. Actually, this:

> ```
> static string XsltPath = "~/Controls/DumpKeys.xslt";
> ```

Should really be this:

```
private static readonly string XsltPath = "~/Controls/DumpKeys.xslt";
```

Now, in order to turn that LINQ jam into a simple `Controls.Add(xml);` instruction, things need to happen.

```
var xml = new Xml 
{ 
    DocumentContent = CreateDocumentContent(),
    TransformSource = XsltPath
};
```

The `CreateDocumentContent()` method could be where that LINQ query lives.

```
private string CreateDocumentContent()
{
    return new XElement("keys", Keys.Select(CreateKeyElement)).ToString();
}
```

And that `CreateKeyElement` method group, extracted to its own one-liner method again, makes it pretty clear what's going on:

```
private XElement CreateKeyElement(string key)
{
    return new XElement("key", new XAttribute("name", key), this[key]);
}
```

Cramming all these functions into a single instruction is making maintenance much harder than it needs to be.

---

> ```
> abstract protected string this[string index] { get; }
> ```

Maybe it's just me, but in my mind an *index* is an `int` that specifies the *position* of an item in a collection. What you really have here is a `string name` for accessing the values in some dictionary; correctly naming the indexer parameter can avoid confusion here.

Comment: Why wouldn't `XsltPath` be a `const`?

Comment: @TopinFrassi it *could* be, because it's also `private` - but semantically, a path simply isn't a *constant*. But yeah, it doesn't really matter here, that the path gets burned into the call sites at compilation, since the call sites are all within the same assembly. If the value was `public`, and consumed in another assembly, changing the value of the constant would require re-compiling the client assembly to pick up the new value - it being `static readonly` instead of `const` avoids that.